# why is tweepy api.create_friendship giving me an unauthorised error

Tags: python, tweepy

Hi i'm using the tweepy library to make the call below. Other calls work but this one throws an unauthorised error. Does anyone know why this is happening?

api.create_friendship(screen_name="example")

gives me a 401 unauthorised error, any idea what i'm doing wrong or how to get permissions to make this call?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have given the app the write permission and re-authorized it.

See [the FAQ in Tweepy's documentation](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.3.0/faq.html#why-am-i-encountering-a-401-unauthorized-error).